# How do I make multiple HTTP requests in parallel in PHP?

Tags: java, php

I have a script written in PHP that sends an API call to eBay. There are several (15-50) calls made every second. I did some benchmarking and noticed that PHP doesn't execute these as fast as I'd like since it doesn't run them in parallel.

My question: Is it a good idea to convert the script into Java, so as to give it multi-threaded capabilities? Will this even run each request in parallel like I think it would or am I misguided to believe so?

Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: I have retitled your question to not be so incredibly misleading.  Your question ultimately has little to do with performance and everything to do with being able to make many HTTP requests in parallel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, rewriting your script in Java is not going to magically make it multithreaded, and unless you have experience with concurrent programming I would avoid this.  Even then this doesn't necessarily mean it will run faster than your PHP script.

Second, PHP can execute multiple http requests in parallel using cURL's multi exec functions.  See the docs for [curl_multi_init](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) and [curl_multi_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) for how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Computer Language Benchmark Shootout Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=java&lang2=php)

Java 1.71 PHP 63.19 so Java is about 37x faster.

Comment: According to that chart, Java 6 - server is ~30 times faster than PHP.

Comment: These benchmarks are completely useless in this situation, since it is almost certainly the network I/O blocking that is slowing down the script.  A single-threaded Java app will hardly be any faster than the OP's PHP script.

Comment: @Dan Simon - Perhaps karmakaze's answer is more understandable given that the question was initially titled "PHP vs JAVA performance" ;-) You are correct that once we understand the question *should be* about how to make "many HTTP requests in parallel" we can see that the answer won't be found by comparing the performance of different programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java, you certainly *could* use the [Threads API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) to execute requests in parallel (probably using a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)). That said, adding concurrency does not guarantee that the code will execute in less time overall.

Do you know that the PHP code is even the bottleneck in execution? It could very well be that the eBay API throttles requests, so that you can only send a fixed number of requests per second, in which case it really doesn't matter how fast *your* code is. Or, it could be the case that you have a really slow network, or really high latency — again, your time would be better spent fixing those problems first.

Answer (score 0):

How about using multiple invisible frames so the browser can process them in parallel and having the visible page feed requests to the frames and incorporate the responses client-side?

Answer (score -1):

PHP has support for threading if you compile it in [via PCNTL](http://php.net/pcntl) which could potentially save you more time then re-writing a lot of the large network libraries in Java.

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The PCNTL extension does *not* provide **threading**.  It adds POSIX process controls, which can help writing an application that works by *forking* processes.